# Why does this nested loop have memory traffic N(N+1) instead of N^2?

Tags: algorithm, memory, optimization, hardware

I was reading through a textbook earlier this afternoon about memory access optimization techniques, such as unroll and jam, and the book provided this as an example for consideration (before optimization):

```
do i=1,N
  do j=1,N
    sum = sum + foo(A(i),B(j))
  enddo
enddo
```

Looking at this, what immediately pops into my head is that the memory traffic should be N^2.  However, the explanation following the code explains that the total memory traffic is actually N(N+1).  Why would that be?

My best guess basically goes like this:  N(N+1) = N^2 + N.  The N^2 is coming from loading up all of array B (which has size N) a total of N times (due to the outer loop), and the N is coming from loading up all of A (which has size N) exactly 1 time (as the outer loop runs to completion once).

Is that accurate?  Or is there something perhaps going on with loading the signature of foo, or reading/writing the variable `sum`, or another sneaky thing that I'm not considering that results in the +1 term?  I know this is a relatively simple problem of this sort, but I want to make sure that I'm thinking about this class of problems in the right way before moving on to harder problems.

Comment: By N(N+1) do you mean O(N(N+1))?

Comment: complexity of this algorithm is O(N^2) in both cases, Not sure but I think that Regardless of N, the innermost function is executing once per execution of the second loop + the last operation that sum the foo (that's why we are adding one, try to think using decision tree model).

Comment: @TomerZ - actually I think that's what may be confusing me as well.  I'm very used to algorithmic complexity, and possibly so used to it that I just immediately saw twice-nested for loops and assumed it must be O(N^2).  I agree that the memory traffic must be O(N^2), but the book definitely does specify N(N+1) in particular =\